# FB Litho: How to set custom font for Text

Tags: android, facebook, litho, facebook-litho

My question is how to set a custom font for `Text` component in Facebook's UI framework **Litho**?

The following is my `Text` component:

```
 Text.create(componentContext)
                .flexGrow(1f)
                .verticalGravity(VerticalGravity.CENTER)
                .text("MY APP")
                .textSizeDip(25)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER)
```

Comment: This document [1] shows that there's a typeface prop I have no idea about usage though.


  [1]: https://fblitho.com/javadoc/com/facebook/litho/widget/Text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the `typeface` prop, you must first obtain a `Typeface` object, which is significantly easier if you can use Support Library v26, which introduces [Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html) ... it's pretty simple to do so from a `ComponentContext` even inside your `onCreateLayout` method (though presumably you may wish to cache the `Typeface`):

```
Text.create(c)
    .typeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(
        c.getApplicationContext, R.font.my_cool_font)
    .text("Check out my cool font")
    .build()
```

There is also a `Typeface.Builder` class available if you do not have access to Support v26, which gives you a few options about how to specify the desired font.